# Quickly merge tables with keys that are one-to-one and onto

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have two tables with a hundred million rows each.  I'm trying to update one of them with columns that are currently unique to the other.  The properties of the tables would seem to make an update (relatively) fast, but the operation has been going for too long and I wonder what I'm missing. Here are the schemata:

```
CREATE TABLE original
(
  some_old_var varchar(48),
  some_other_old_var varchar(48),
  --- lots of other variables
  new_var_one smallint, --- this is empty, full of null values, I just added it in anticipation of the merge (UPDATE) below
  new_var_two smallint, --- ditto
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
);
CREATE TABLE new_vars
(
  new_var_one smallint,  --- this is new data I want to merge into original
  new_var_two smallint,  --- ditto
  id INT PRIMARY KEY     --- the mapping of this id and original.id is one-to-one and onto; tables new_vars and original have exactly the same number of rows.
);
```

And this is the slow operation:

```
UPDATE original SET new_var_one = new_vars.new_var_one, new_var_two = new_vars.new_var_two FROM new_vars WHERE original.id = new_vars.id;
```

If I was a computer I'd sort the two tables on id and just zip them up.  Is there a way to tell the db to do that? Should I be doing this with ALTER instead?

(For a bit more info, I'm processing table original outside of db and trying to get the new data back in.  I got original.some_old_var into R, crunched it to get two new vars, and wrote them back up to db in a way that preserved the id of each row. The final step is to get the new vars back into original.  That's way original.id is autoincrementing and new_vars.id isn't. Could that be a part of the problem?)

EDIT: EXPLAIN ANALYZE took too long, but here is EXPLAIN:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/BHH

The planner seems to have chosen smart.  But this is all on a laptop so I figure its a RAM problem and I'll be dividing the update into parts.  Thanks.

Comment: could you post query plan to see what's happening?

Comment: The update will need disk I/O of at least 3 * size of your new_vars table: two to read the source and destination rows, and once to write them (creating new row versions, which will also need yet another pass for vacuum, eventually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I was a computer I'd sort the two tables on id and just zip them
>   up.

It is called `MERGE JOIN` and will be done automatically by query optimizer (if this query plan is actually the best from optimizer perspective). Other options are `HASH JOIN` (will probably be better for this case) or `NESTED LOOP JOIN` (will only be effective on small number of rows).

You do not have to worry about it at all. Postgres query optimizer will pick the best query plan for you.

You can check the actual query plan by using `EXPLAIN UPDATE original ...` or `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) UPDATE original ...`

If you have problems with query execution times - you need to gather information like described [`here`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Guide_to_reporting_problems) or [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). With this information we will be able to help you.

BTW You do not need to offload data from postgres to process it. You can use one of built in procedural languages inside postgres (and `PL/R` is one of them).

Comment: @user1073999 If you want to learn about postgres - the best option is to read postgres manual [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html). It will take you some time to read it all, but the benefits are well worth it.